# Websphere Application server is not starting

Tags: websphere, rad

Everytime I try to start the Websphere 8.5 server I get below error/warning infinitely. Do you know how to resolve this? Any pointers to what could be causing this?

```
 [10/7/14 15:40:48:391 EDT] 0000003b HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector (initialization failure)
[10/7/14 15:40:49:402 EDT] 00000055 HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector (initialization failure)
[10/7/14 15:40:50:409 EDT] 0000003c HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector (initialization failure)
[10/7/14 15:40:51:412 EDT] 00000054 HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector (initialization failure)
[10/7/14 15:40:52:415 EDT] 00000056 HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector (initialization failure)
[10/7/14 15:40:53:419 EDT] 0000003b HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector (initialization failure)
[10/7/14 15:40:54:428 EDT] 00000055 HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector (initialization failure)
```

Comment: Can be cause by many issues check this link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266028

Comment: Is there anything else in the logs besides this? I am assuming you are trying to start this from within RAD (as you have tagged rad). Does it make any difference if you start trying it externally? Are there any FFDCs that are generated? Have you examined them.

Comment: There is a big sysout log that is there, I don't know how to share it here. @Gas Thank you for the link. It did help a bit but didn't address the exact problem.

Comment: Stop the server, remove SystemOut.log and paste first exception from that log that you see during startup.

Comment: or if you could use this link. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=13e27be0-a6cc-45ab-8368-f40a60b85feb 
I've the complete stack trace attached here.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your log. It is not happening every time, but only since you polluted your server classpath with lots of third party libs. This is not the correct way to add custom shared libraries to the server.

Please remove all entries starting with `C:\_pk\code\_CodeRepository\projects` from the server classpath as they are conflicting with WAS libraries.

If you need to have custom libraries for your applications create it via Environment > Shared libraries and then attach to the server via classloader or to application via shared libarary configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me try this will post you.

Comment: @pratikch Please provide some more details, what have you done, and what is the result. You can clean SystemOut.log restart the server and attach log as previously.

Comment: I did this to add 'shared libraries' to the project.
creating shared library---
1. Navigate to Environment -> Shared Libraries
2. a specific name to shared libraries in name text box.
3. the paths of the libraries where i stored all your jars in Classpath like: C:\_pk\code\_CodeRepository\projects
4. apply and save it

Assigning to a server

servers -> Applicaiton servers -> server1 -> Java and Process management  -> create new (parent last)classloader -->saved--> Shared library references-->library reference created in above step. Saved.

Comment: @pratikch In the classpath in shared library you have to enter all the jars, each jar in separate line e.g. <path>/myjar1.jar <enter> <path>/myjar2.jar etc... not just the path to folder with jars.

Comment: @Gas Yeah did it the same way you explained in here, Before you actually said so. ie. each jar on separate line. The Path mentioned was just as an example.

Comment: @pratikch And after you removed these classes from server classpath, you still have same errors? Can you put new systemOut.log?

Comment: I've updated the logs on the https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=13e27be0-a6cc-45ab-8368-f40a60b85feb

Please note the classloader strategy selected is "Classes loaded with parent class loader first".

Comment: @pratikch So your `SOAPConnector (initialization failure)` error is solved. I don't see it in the logs any more.

Comment: Yes but still there are problems.